# Django factory boy post_generation in field with default value don't work

Tags: django, python-3.x, factory-boy, pytest-django

I have a model with a field that is a int type, that field have a default value

I'm trying to set a value in that field with post_generation but nothing is happening, the field stay with the default value, when I try to use .set I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'set'
```

this is the field that I'm trying to populate

```
@factory.post_generation
def priority(obj, create, extracted, **kwargs):
    for series in range(obj.patrimony.count()): # this is a sequence of numbers
        series += 1
        obj.priority.set(series)
```

and this is the model, is just a simple model

```
class Series(models.Model):
    priority = models.IntegerField(_("Priority"), default=0, null=True)
```

Can someone open my eyes please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are meeting two issues:

#### Setting the field value

`Series.priority` is always an `int`, and integers have no `.set()` method (they are immutable objects).
You should set it by using `obj.priority = series`

#### Setting the value at the right time

factory_boy creates objects in 3 steps:
1. Evaluate all pre-declarations (`LazyAttribute`, `Sequence`, etc.);
2. Create the object in the database (calling `Series.objects.create(...)`)
3. Evaluate post-generation declarations

If `obj.patrimony` is known before *creating* the series, you could simply have:

```
class SeriesFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Series
    priority = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.patrimony.count())
```

(I've also adjusted the declaration, since your `for series in ...` loop is strictly equivalent to `obj.priority = obj.patrimony.count()`)

Comment: Thank you very much, know I understand a litttle more about evaluation in factory boy :D